# Cheap alcoholic drinks for winters in Europe

Tags: budget, europe, food-and-drink, alcohol

Generally I go for beer when I am in Europe, but I want to avoid it during peak winter season to avoid sore throat.

What are the best alternatives to beer that can be taken in large volumes?

EDIT:

In Europe, i will be visiting Germany, Austria, Czech Republic, Iceland

Comment: Where in Europe are you going?

Comment: @jpatokal : I have edited my query and added countries which i am visiting.

Comment: Best by what standard? Have you considered water?

Comment: You could order cider. I don't know if it is another potential cause of sore throat, but I have never heard of that being a problem with beer either.

Comment: @Airsick: See the question...water is non alcoholic 

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: No alcoholic drinks should ever be drunk in large volumes. If you want to drink a lot, drink alcohol free and if you want a little buzz, you can add one or a few small (hard) alcohol drinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Mulled wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulled_wine)** (German: *Glühwein*, Czech: *Svařák*) is a hot beverage made from wine and spices that's ubiquitous in Germany, Austria and the Czech Republic as well in the winter.  The canonical place to drink it is at an outdoor Christmas market, although most pubs, bars etc will offer it as well.  The one catch is that it's usually not the kind of thing you'd drink in "large quantities", but that's a relative measure.

You can find mulled wine in Ireland as well these days, but **hot cider** (alcoholic apple juice/beer) is a more traditional alternative.  **Irish coffee** (hot coffee with whiskey) is also nice, but drinking more than one would be unusual due to the caffeine content.

Comment: You give good tips for Ireland, but the question mentions *Iceland*.

Comment: Doesn't fit "cheap". In Munich it's now 4 Euro for a small cup.